# nginx stream map with wildcard

Tags: nginx, regex, pcre

I am really bad with regex. I am trying to do this in nginx:

```
stream {

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        api.dom1.com dom1_backend;
        *.dom2.com dom2_backend;
    }

    upstream dom1_backend {
        server api.dom1.com:443;
    }

    upstream dom2_api_backend {
        server *.dom3.com:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $name;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

How do I get dom2 working? I just need to map a wildcard domain back to wildcard domain.

Mean anything *.dom2.com will go to *.dom3.com

Answer (score 5):

In order to use hostnames you should specify [the special `hostnames` parameter to `map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_map_module.html#map). This allows for asterisk wildcards to be interpreted in the manner you expect.

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    hostnames;
    api.dom1.com dom1_backend;
    *.dom2.com dom2_backend;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the map block. What about the upstream block? Doesn't work with hostnames parameter.

`server *.dom3.com:443;`

Comment: @abubin Huh? That doesn't even make any sense. There's no such host. You have to name a specific server.

Comment: oh..I wanted to make wildcard to wildcard. EG, aaa.dom2.com to aaa.dom3.com, bbb.dom2.com to bbb.dom3.com, x11.dom2.com to x11.dom3.com... is that even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think with map you may won't need upstream any more, try this:

```
stream {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        hostnames;
        api.dom1.com dom1_backend;
        *.dom2.com   dom2_backend;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        listen 6443;
        proxy_pass $name:$server_port;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if their upstream has multiple hosts?